# Tensorflow: model.fit -- TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, classification

I am relatively new to ML and am working on an image classification problem. I have various images organized into 13 classes in separate train and validation/test datasets. Here are some snippets from my code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(13, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                        train_dir, 
                                        batch_size=75, 
                                        class_mode='categorical', 
                                        target_size=(150, 150))

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                        validation_dir, 
                                        batch_size=75, 
                                        class_mode='categorical', 
                                        target_size=(150, 150))

history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                    epochs=15, 
                    steps_per_epoch=58, 
                    validation_data=validation_generator, 
                    validation_steps=15)
```

The error I am seeing follows model.fit as I am attempting to train the model. Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? See the error message below for more context.

```
Train for 58 steps, validate for 15 steps
Epoch 1/15
 1/58 [..............................] - ETA: 10:22
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1393f2e1df7b> in <module>
      3                     steps_per_epoch=58,
      4                     validation_data=validation_generator,
----> 5                     validation_steps=15)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 13
     [[node metrics/accuracy/Squeeze (defined at /home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1030]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Comment: Please add full error message.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added the full error message.

Comment: What is the output when you create your `train_generator` and `validation_generator`?

Comment: Why there is no comma after `batch_size=75 ` and `class_mode='categorical'` in `validation_generator`?

Comment: Half your code is missing and not indented properly

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat the output prints out the number of images in each set and the expected number of classes (i.e. 4288 images in 13 classes). I am using Jupyter notebooks to segment my code and don't see any issues until the last line

Comment: At this point, I am not sure of what is happening. If possible just share a collab file with the link dataset if possible. I will do some experiments on it.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat after restarting my machine and testing again, I received a different error that may be more relevant to understanding the issue. I updated this above.

Comment: This error is pretty easy to solve. Just set `class_mode='sparse'`.